# Access Props inside const in React Native - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've created a const like this:

```
 const DrawerNav =  DrawerNavigator({

    Home:{
        screen:StackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
        }
    },
    MonthlyReport: {
        screen:MonthlyReport
    }

},{
    contentComponent: () => <DrawerContent item={props.item}/>
})
```

Now I access this using:

```
  <DrawerNav item={item}/>
```

But I'm unable to access the props passed inside `DrawerNav`. How can I access this in:

`<DrawerContent item={props.item}/>`

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to get the prop parameter:

```
contentComponent: props => (
  <DrawerContent {...props} />
)
```

Then just pass using a spread opperator

Comment: But the props here doesn’t contain the passed item. They only contain the navigation props.